# Chosen- on Ajax loaded select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-chosen

I have the select drop-down element which is loaded dynamically from ajax call, I want to search option on that select.
I used Chosen jquery plugin for my select, but that doesn't work since select element was not available(loaded on ajax response) when chosen loaded during document ready function.

I tried explicitly call 
`jQuery(".chosen").chosen();` after `div` loaded in Ajax but that also didn't help.

**My Ajax call is:**

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: "action=getVMList,
             success: function(response) {              
                $('#vmList').innerHTML=response;

                 //Explicitly call chosen after ajax response. 
                 jQuery(".chosen").chosen();

                }       
        });
```

**Response DIV for ajax is**

```
<select class="AllVmList chosen" multiple id="select4${index}" >
    <c:forEach var="vm" items="${vmList}">
        <option><c:out value="${vm}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Your approach is correct actually. I have done this before, and rerunning `jQuery(".chosen").chosen();` after the AJAX call should work just fine. Can you post a JS fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks,
it worked don't know how, but I just changed element ID instead of element class to load chosen

Comment: You should post the updated code in an answer, and accept that answer so that this question doesn't appear in the list of unanswered question anymore and others facing a similar issue will get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems issue was with some cache.
Worked